# Has or is with Plot?

Tags: word-choice

This has an interesting plot?
Or:
This is an interesting plot?

Which one?

And why?

When listening to a story and you commented "this has an interesting plot or this is an interesting plot'
Which one?

I am confused.

Comment: You are using the pronoun "this" to refer to different things in your sentences, so they have different meanings. The reference is determined by the verb used (either "has" or "is"), and this usage is not restricted to sentences with the noun "plot".

Comment: As Margana says, in _this is an interesting plot_, **this** means **the plot**. When you say _this has an interesting plot_, **this** means **this play** (or book, or movie, ...).

Answer (score 3):

If you say "This *has* an interesting plot", the word *this* refers to the story you have been listening to: the story has an interesting plot.

If you say "This *is* an interesting plot", the word *this* refers to the plot itself: the plot is interesting.